# React: unwanted multiple instances of same component

Tags: reactjs

My Dashboard React component renders multiple child components. When I change the state of the parent component (dashboard), multiple instances of the child components are created. They are then stacked on top of each other:
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Vjc.jpg)

Obviously this is not what I want! Every component should only be displayed once.

Here is a simplified example:

```
 state = {
 goal : ''
}
 _refresh = () => {
    this.setState({
      goal: '5'
    })
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='card'>
          <div className='heading'>
            <p style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>CURRENT WEIGHT</p>
            {this.state.goal}
            <button onClick={this._refresh}>hallo</button>
          </div>
          <CurrentPlot currentWeight={this.props.currentWeight} />
        </div>
        <div className='card'>
          <div className='heading'>
            <p>YOUR STATS</p>
          </div>
          <StatsPlot
            xData={this.props.xData}
            yData={this.props.yData}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

So whenever the button is clicked and the state is set, multiple instances of the plots are created.

And here is the root component from where the above component is rendered:

```
return (
<Switch>
<Route path='/dashboard' render={() => (
        <Dashboard //all the props />
)}/>
more routes..
</Switch>
)
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: How is your parent component rendered

Comment: As a route using react-router, within the <Switch> tags.

Comment: This can happen when rendering crashes. Any errors in your console? Is `StatsPlot` using some library that dynamically adds components?

Comment: No, no errors whatsoever, everything renders as it should. Just too many times. Yes, both plots use plot.ly. You could be onto something there, since I think it only affects those plots! How would I prevent this from happening?

Comment: can you make in codesandbox? it's kinda hard to sus out the problem without all the bits... ya know